# Orthogonality vs perpendicularity of planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I have two planes and I wanna check whether they are orthogonal and I am not sure if I am correct.

If I understand this correctly an orthogonality is just a multi-vector extension of perpendicularity so checking whether two planes are orthogonal is the same as checking whether they are perpendicular. If I have two planes:

\begin{equation}
2a − b + c = 6
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a + 5b + 3c = 2
\end{equation}

I just need to check their normal vector dot product which is:

\begin{equation}
v_1 \cdot v_2 = <2, -1,1> \cdot < 1, 5, 3> = 2 - 5 + 3 = 0
\end{equation}

and since its 0 the two planes are orthogonal right? Or is this just perpendicularity and to check whether they are orthogonal I need to do something more

Comment: Two planes are orthogonal is and only if they are perpendicular, it is the same thing.

Comment: To be clear, orthogonal and perpendicular are two words which mean the same thing.

Comment: @Joppy I always thought so but I am bit confused because if I understand the textbook text completely there are not the same thing in more than 3d and I wasn’t sure if in less than 3d there are maybe some other special rules

Comment: @Joppy I don’t think they’re quite the same. For instance, the zero vector is orthogonal to everything, but one doesn’t usually call it perpendicular to anything. Orthogonality can be viewed as a generalization of the geometric notion of perpendicularity. One can speak of orthogonal functions, where there’s no obvious geometric interpretation. To be sure, when working in a Euclidean space, they are for all practical purposes pretty much synonymous, as you say.

Comment: @amd Thanks this is exactly what I needed to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re not quite the same in my mind. I think of orthogonality as a generalization of the geometric idea of perpendicularity. One can speak of a pair of functions being orthogonal even though there’s no obvious geometric interpretation of this relationship. When you’re working in a Euclidean space they’re pretty much synonymous, although even there “orthogonal” is the more general term: the zero vector is orthogonal to everything, but one doesn’t usually describe it as being perpendicular to anything.

For the curious, the word “perpendicular” derives from the Latin for “plumb line,” so at root it has the notion of hanging straight down or standing straight up from the ground. The word “orthogonal,” on the other hand, means “right angled” or “straight angled,” so even in their etymology the latter seems to me like a more broadly-applicable term.